# What does this egrep command do?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

What does this `egrep` command do?

```
egrep '[^A-M][0-9]+' /etc/passwd
```

So far I think it searches for any file in `/etc/passwd` that starts with A-M and includes the number(s) 0-9. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` at the beginning of an expression means "beginning of line".  However, `^` inside a bracket expression matches everything *not* in that expression.  So, for example, while `[abcd]` matches the letters a, b, c, or d, the expression `[^abcd]` matches everything other than those letters.

So the expression you've got matches "anything not A-M, followed by 1 or more digits".

The following lines would all match that expression:

```
mmmmmz09123
00
this is a very long line that includes the number 1.
```

Because they all contain a digit preceded by something that is not in the range A-M.

Comment: Thanks for helping and correcting me. egrep and it's expressions are very much clear to me now, awesome!

Comment: I'm glad this helped out!  If you like the answer you may want to mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the checkbox on the left.  Thanks!